# Windows Phone 8 - Scrollable TextBox

Tags: textbox, windows-phone-8, scrollview, windows-phone

I have the problem that the user can enter text as long as he wants, but if the visual part of TextBox is full filled, it does not autoscroll to the new line.

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,12">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <toolkit:PhoneTextBox x:Name="PinNameTextBox" Hint="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Untitled, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBox x:Name="PinContentTextBox" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" InputScope="Text" />
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

I have also tried the ScrollViewer but it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this was already the same case with WP7; from what I've heard it is a platform restriction that causes UIElements like e.g. TextBoxes to be clipped if they exceed 2048px.

You could try to create an own TextBox control with a similar approach to what was done
[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx), though. Hope that helps.

Comment: UIElements are indeed limited to 2048x2048px in size (on ScaleFactor 100)